# Docker image lifecycle for a java-based app

Tags: java, docker, cloud

I am trying to get more familiar with docker, and I was wondering what's the best practice and lifecycle for running a java-webapp as a service using docker.

Should my image have tomcat already running, or should I start tomcat on running the image ?

I would be using a data-volume for persisting storage. What would be the state of that container ? always running, or just have a container in a stopped state.

If my app-container stops, what would happen if I restart it ? Will it resume at the state it was stopped, or it will be a clean restart from the top ?

Comment: How can an image have anything running already? It's just a file system snapshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to setup a container having the tomcat server binaries in it. And also copy the custom java-webapp to the tomcat server's webapps folder so that it is loaded automatically each time tomcat is started up. And for this container, you can specify the entry point to be the startup.sh script available in the tomcat bin folder. So each time you start the docker container with run command, the tomcat server would be started and in turn load your java-webapp.

If you want the tomcat up and running all the time, then yes the container should be in the running state. Note that any changes that you do as part of the custom app in the tomcat or any changes to the tomcat configurations, you will need to use the docker commit to save the state of the container as a new image or overwrite the existing image. Else, if the container stops, all the changes will be lost and go back to original configuration when the container was built. So yes, if the container stops, it will be a clean restart from the top as in the tomcat server will be started up again and load the java-webapp.